# Compare 2 different dataframes in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe with same column names. I want to compare all rows with each other.

I want to compare all the parameter values and results in df1, with same parameters and results in df2.

Thank you.

```
df1:
Parameters            Result
xxx                     yes
yyy                     no


df2:
Parameters            Result
xxx                     yes
yyy                     no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary same order of `Parameters` and same length of both `DataFrame`s, then is possible use:

```
df2['new'] = np.where(df1['Result'].eq(df2['Result']), 'OK', '')
```

If possible order is different or length is different use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equal:

```
s = df2['Parameters'].map(df1.set_index('Parameters')['Result'])

df2['new'] = np.where(s.eq(df2['Result']), 'OK', '')
print (df2)
               Parameters Result new
0    PubkeyAuthentication     no    
1         PermitRootLogin     ys    
2  PasswordAuthentication     no    
3    PermitEmptyPasswords     no  OK
4           X11Forwarding     no  OK
5              AllowUsers   user  OK
```

Comment: @stdntt - Then use second solution.

Comment: @stdntt - It is same like `==` Or `df2['new'] = np.where(s == df2['Result'], 'OK', '')`

Comment: @stdntt - Some problem with solution?